# breaking contour across image border into lines

Tags: opencv, graphics

I use the function `findContours` to find the borders of the driveway. However, since the driveway usually comes across the image, I get polygons like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZWOw.png). What I really like is line instances, so I am wondering is there any way to break the polygon into [line instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcswD.png).

Answer (score 1):

You can use approxPolyDP to simplify a contour down into larger lines.

The epsilon value specifies the minimum length for each line segment.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

# turns a list into a tuple
def tup(arr):
    return (int(arr[0]), int(arr[1]));

# load image
img = cv2.imread("rect.png");
img = img[:,1:]; # there's a weird thing on the left side

# get mask
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 10, 255);

# dilate and erode to clean up lines
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8);
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 2);
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 2);

# get contour # OpenCV 3.4, Other versions will return (countours, _)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# get approximate lines
epsilon = 0.005*cv2.arcLength(contours[0],True); # epsilon is the minimum length of the line
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[0],epsilon,True);

# draw lines
for a in range(len(approx)):
    color = [random.randint(0,255) for col in range(3)];
    start = approx[a-1][0]; # points have an extra layer of brackets
    end = approx[a][0];
    cv2.line(img, tup(start), tup(end), color, 2);
    
# show
cv2.imshow("img", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can break contour into lines. Now the question is the same lane with curvature is broken into multiple lines. Can I merge them together? @Ian

Comment: You can modify the epsilon value to change the line lengths. This method also returns the points of the lines so if you want to merge two lines together you can delete the middle point.